# Playing two videos in one Video element React

Tags: reactjs

I want to put a short intro video that plays before every video on my web app. This fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bnzqkpza/ has a lot of the functionality I'm looking for, but I am using React so I need to rewrite the jquery so it doesn't change the DOM. I'm new to React, can anyone help me with this?

HTML:

```
<video src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" id="myvideo" width="320" height="240" controls style="background:black">
</video>
```

JS:

```
var myvid = document.getElementById('myvideo');
var myvids = [
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "http://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
  ];
var activeVideo = 0;

myvid.addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
  // update the active video index
  activeVideo = (++activeVideo) % myvids.length;

  // update the video source and play
  myvid.src = myvids[activeVideo];
  myvid.play();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I created a sample in CodeSandbox. The Video component would look something like this:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

export default class Video extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      index: 0,
      src: this.props.videos[0]
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let video = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    video.addEventListener("ended", e => {
      if (this.state.index < this.props.videos.length - 1) {
        let nextIndex = this.state.index + 1;
        this.setState({
          index: nextIndex,
          src: this.props.videos[nextIndex]
        });
      }
    });
    video.play();
  }
  componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    let video = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    video.play();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <video
        src={this.state.src}
        controls
        autplay="true"
        playsinline
        muted
        crossorigin
      />
    );
  }
}
```

The code sandbox url: https://codesandbox.io/s/n7p9yvp260

Comment: Thank you, this solution is exactly what I'm looking for. Unfortunately I have many handler functions that call this.id on my current video. Hopefully I can adapt this.

Comment: @Waduhek I'm not sure if I understand what you are asking. You can put this `Video` component into any other React Component. If you want a particular video to load first, put that video as the first item of the array.

Answer (score 0):

**Edited to use React 16 example.**

You can try something like this:

```
const urls = [
  "https://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4", 
  "https://www.w3schools.com/html/movie.mp4"
];

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      currentUrlIdx: 0,
    }

    this.handleEnded = this.handleEnded.bind(this);
  }

  handleEnded(e) {
    const nextUrlIdx = (this.state.currentUrlIdx + 1) % urls.length
    this.setState({ currentUrlIdx: nextUrlIdx });
  }

  render() {
    return <div>
      <video src={urls[this.state.currentUrlIdx]} autoPlay onEnded={this.handleEnded}/>
    </div>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OOxmjJ?editors=0010

Comment: What exactly do those DOM Nodes do? I have something similar to this approach, with an index as a state variable. Since I don't need the videos to loop, I set the index to 1 in an endHandler method after the index 0 video ends. I am printing out the result, and my state variable is successfully changing to 1, but the index 0 video keeps replaying instead of moving on. Other places online say that this.setState should re-render the html but that doesn't seem to be the case for me.
I don't have any of these calls to getDOMNode or videoDOMNode

Comment: I just edited my answer. I realized that the Codepen I used for the example, used an ancient version of React and that explains why things that I expected to work weren't working. It is much simpler in React 16 because the onEnded event works and you don't have to access the DOM directly.